# WCF Change message encoding from Utf-16 to Utf-8

Tags: wcf, utf-8, .net-core

I have a WCF connected service in a .net core application. I'm using the code that is autogenerated taken the wsdl definition.

Currently at the top of the request xml is including this line:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>`

I can't find a simple way to change this encoding to UTF-8 when sending the request.

Since I could find a configuration option a the request/client objects, I've tried to change the message with following code at `IClientMessageInspector.BeforeSendRequest`

```
    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {
        // Load a new xml document from current request
        var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDocument.LoadXml(request.ToString());
        ((XmlDeclaration)xmlDocument.FirstChild).Encoding = Encoding.UTF8.HeaderName;

        // Create streams to copy 
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(memoryStream);

        xmlDocument.Save(xmlWriter);
        xmlWriter.Flush();
        xmlWriter.Close();
        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(memoryStream);

        // Create a new message
        var newMessage = Message.CreateMessage(request.Version, null, xmlReader);
        newMessage.Headers.CopyHeadersFrom(request);
        newMessage.Properties.CopyProperties(request.Properties);
        return null;
    }
```

But the newMessage object still writes the xml declaration using utf-16. I can see it while debugging at the watch window since.

Any idea on how to accomplish this (should be) simple change will be very apreciated.

Comment: The default text encoding for [<basicHttpBindiung>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/basichttpbinding) *is* UTF8. What binding did you use? If you want to change the encoding, do so at the binding level, don't try to modify how the serializer works.

Comment: In any case, `BeforeSendRequest` is meant to inspect and modify the message, not serialize it. Serialization has its own overloads. You don't need to use them though is you want to communicate with stantads-compliant SOAP services

Comment: UTF8 is the default encoding for [wsHttpBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/wshttpbinding) too.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this problem? I'm having the same issue, and I can't seem to find a solution. This seems like it should be so easy.

Answer (score 0):

Which binding do you use to create the communication channel? The textmessageencoding element which has been contained in the CustomBinding generally contains TextEncoding property.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/textmessageencoding
WriteEncoding property specifies the character set encoding to be used for emitting messages on the binding. Valid values are

- UnicodeFffeTextEncoding: Unicode BigEndian encoding
- Utf16TextEncoding: Unicode encoding
- Utf8TextEncoding: 8-bit encoding

The default is Utf8TextEncoding. This attribute is of type Encoding.
As for the specific binding, it contains the textEncoding property too.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding.textencoding?view=netframework-4.0
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.