# C# Generate SOAP Envelope without XML Root Element

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, soap

I'm using `Message.CreateMessage` to create a `Message` and send it to a WCF Service Endpoint but every message i create begins with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>` which causes the Service to reject my messages with `Operation is not supported`. The [SOAP 1.1 standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383494) states that `The Envelope is the top element of the XML document representing the message.` which is probably why the Service is rejecting my messages. The different `MessageVersion`s don't change the resulting XML and the constructor does accept a `BodyWriter` but the XML body isn't causing my problem, it's the root element.

Is there a way i can generate a `Message` with `Message.CreateMessage` without the XML Root Element?

The Code

```
internal static Message CreateGetMessage(string id)
{
    const string Get = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/transfer/Get";
    const string Rm = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/11/ResourceManagement";

    /* unnecessary code removed to create simplest example */

    var message = Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.Default, Get);

    if (message.Headers.FindHeader("ResourceReferenceProperty", Rm) <= 0)
    {
        message.Headers.Add(MessageHeader.CreateHeader("ResourceReferenceProperty", Rm, id));
    }

    return message;
}
```

The resulting SOAP Envelope

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/transfer/Get</a:Action>
    <ResourceReferenceProperty xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/11/ResourceManagement">8f2a4ecc-e3dc-1a4c-5a28-4a4a7a8e6644</ResourceReferenceProperty>
</s:Header>
<s:Body />
</s:Envelope>
```

The desired SOAP Envelope

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/transfer/Get</a:Action>
    <ResourceReferenceProperty xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/11/ResourceManagement">8f2a4ecc-e3dc-1a4c-5a28-4a4a7a8e6644</ResourceReferenceProperty>
</s:Header>
<s:Body />
</s:Envelope>
```

Debugging

[image: WCF Error]

Comment: The only way I found of removing the utf-16 error is to use readline to skip processing the line.  See following answer as an example : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65331628/how-to-loop-through-complex-xml-nodes-in-xml-file-and-select-values-based-on-a-l/65341311#65341311

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>` is not the root element, it's the [**XML declaration**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-prolog-dtd). I did find [WCF Change message encoding from Utf-16 to Utf-8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54837696/3744182) and [Can you change the XML Declaration of a WCF Client Request? If so, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57348502/3744182), you might check to see if those help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Message Formatter provided by the .NET to customize the SOAP message, implement the IDispatchMessageFormatter interface on the server side, and implement the IClientMessageFormatter interface on the client side. This is the recommended method.

There is also a message inspector to modify the SOAP message. Here is a sample of message inspector.

```
 public class CustomMessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
    {
        public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
        {
            MessageHeader header = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("UserAgent", "http://User", "User1");
            request.Headers.Add(header);
            return null;
        }

        public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
        {
            MessageHeader header1 = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("Testreply", "http://Test", "Test");
            reply.Headers.Add(header1);
        }
    }
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Interface)]
    public class CustomBehavior : Attribute, IContractBehavior
    {
        public void AddBindingParameters(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
            return;
        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {
            return;
        }
        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, DispatchRuntime dispatchRuntime)
        {
            dispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new CustomMessageInspector());
        }

        public void Validate(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

Add CustomBehavior to your service contract to apply.

```
 [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples")]
    [CustomBehavior]
```

If the message interceptor modifies the message body defined by the service contract, the content verification will fail, so it is recommended to modify only the message header.